# SVG overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I am building up my portefolio and just working on fun projects in general right now. And I amnow working on a weather-app/website. I wanted to spice it up a little and used animated svg in the background. I have never really done this before so now I have gotten into a problem. There is no overflow:hidden in svg. If any of you guys could take a look at my work and see if there are any improvements at this point(because I am clearly not done), and hopefully help me find a solution to the overflow problem that would be great.
I posted it here: http://amolle.com/weather/

// Edit
Css for object containing svg

```
 object {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  right:0;
  object-fit:cover;

  height:100vh;
  bottom:0;
  position: fixed;

}
```

html:

```html
   <div id="all">
  <div class="interface" id="inter">
    <div class="upper">
    <h1 id="location"></h1>
    <h4 id="condition"></h4>
    <div><label >&deg C</label>
       <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
  </label> <label >&deg F</label>
</div>
<h1 id="temp"></h1>

    </div>
  <section class="lower">
<!-- Stuff in here is useless-->>
   </section>
  </div>
 <div class="wrap" id="wrap">
<object id="mysvg" data="bg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" draggable="false">
  
</object>
</div>


 </div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do with the `overflow:hidden`. Like, what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: Please put the details of the problem in the post with a [mcve] of the problem. We shouldn't have to go to a 3rd party site to dig in to your code and find the problem, and that doesn't help people 2 years from now when they search for your problem, land on this post, and your website has changed and no longer illustrates the problem.

Comment: OK BUT which svg has the problem?

Comment: OK, I am sorry guys. Ill edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the answer was pretty simple. All I needed to do was to add another styling:

```
svg{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```